# How to decrease space between ExpansionPanel elements in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my code:

```
ExpansionPanel(
headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
  return SizedBox(
      //height: 20,
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text("Files (2)"),
        leading: Icon(Icons.folder_outlined),
        minLeadingWidth : 4,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0, horizontal: 16.0),
      ),
  );
},
body: Column(
  children: [
    ListTile(
      title: Text("File_0"),
      leading: Icon(Icons.insert_drive_file),
      minLeadingWidth : 4,
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0, horizontal: 16.0),
    ),
    ListTile(
      title: Text("File_1"),
      leading: Icon(Icons.insert_drive_file),
      minLeadingWidth : 4,
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0, horizontal: 16.0),
    )
  ],
),
isExpanded: items[0].isExpanded,
),
```

And this is the result:

[image]

As you see the distance between Folder and files and between files is huge. Could anyone say how to decrease this distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the space/padding on `ExpansionPanelList` calling `expandedHeaderPadding`.

```dart
ExpansionPanelList(
  expandedHeaderPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  children: [
    ExpansionPanel(
```

listTile provide default height based on

```
maxHeight: (isDense ? 48.0 : 56.0) + densityAdjustment.dy,
```

You can create custom row widget for this.

```dart
ExpansionPanel(
  headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text("Files (2)"),
      leading: Icon(Icons.folder_outlined),
      minLeadingWidth: 4,
      contentPadding:
          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0, horizontal: 0.0),
    );
  },
  body: Column(
    children: [
      ...List.generate(
          3,
          (index) => Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, top: 4),
                child: Row(
                  //decorate items the way you like
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.insert_drive_file),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 16,
                    ),
                    Text("File_$index"),
                  ],
                ),
              ))
    ],
  ),
  isExpanded: true,
),
```

More about  [`expandedHeaderPadding`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanelList/expandedHeaderPadding.html) and [`ExpansionPanelList`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanelList-class.html) on flutter.dev.

Comment: Your solution helped to decrease the distance between folder and filles, now it is the same as the distance between the files. But could you also say how to decrease space between files?

Comment: listTile provide default height based on `maxHeight: (isDense ? 48.0 : 56.0) + densityAdjustment.dy,` you can create custom row widget for this.